# How to give an SVG shape a background Image

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image

I have an SVG shape which will have a background Image covering it. I'd like to make this background image CMS editable so rather than just plonk the image in I want to do this with an SVG container that has a background-image assigned to it or at least something I can use to allow PHP to echo out the image if it gets changed via the CMS.

So I've create the desired shape within illustrator and exporting as an SVG provides this code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 208.23 200.22"><defs>
  <style>
    .cls-1{fill:#eeeeef;}
    .cls-2{fill:url(#linear-gradient);}
    .cls-3{fill:url(#linear-gradient-2);}
    .cls-4{fill:url(#linear-gradient-3);}
  </style>
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" y1="108.72" x2="70.49" y2="108.72" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#9bdbf4"/>
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#29b2e7"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#8082be"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="-0.01" y1="189.83" x2="70.49" y2="189.83" xlink:href="#linear-gradient"/>
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-3" x1="-0.01" y1="112.73" x2="70.49" y2="112.73" xlink:href="#linear-gradient"/>
  </defs>
  <title>Asset 1</title>
  <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
      <path class="cls-1" d="M70.28,189.78a149.9,149.9,0,0,1-13.79-8.33A122.87,122.87,0,0,0,70.28,189.78Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M126.47.05C95-.91,55.84,11.75,29.71,33.48l.45-.36c-39.1,52.11-2.4,128.95,37.57,155.47,12.55,6.94,25.83,11.17,38.86,11.57,51.64,1.57,100-27.44,101.58-79.08S178.11,1.62,126.47.05Z"/>
      <path class="cls-2" d="M.59,88.53C.59,68.36,11.43,50.4,27.73,36-25.13,79.85,4.93,146.43,56.49,181.45,25.1,159.62.59,122.29.59,88.53Z"/><path class="cls-3" d="M70.49,189.89l0,0-.17-.09Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="M28.17,35.61l-.44.38C11.43,50.4.59,68.36.59,88.53c0,33.76,24.51,71.09,55.91,92.92a149.9,149.9,0,0,0,13.79,8.33l.17.09C29.69,164.57-9.32,88.88,28.17,35.61Z"/>
      <path class="cls-4" d="M28.17,35.61l-.44.38C11.43,50.4.59,68.36.59,88.53c0,33.76,24.51,71.09,55.91,92.92a149.9,149.9,0,0,0,13.79,8.33l.17.09C29.69,164.57-9.32,88.88,28.17,35.61Z"/>
    </g> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

The grey section I would now like to be covered by an image which does not overflow from the grey svg container.

Can't seem to find anything that really addresses this format of svg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity I've simplified your code.

I'm using your grey path as a path for a `clipPath` element, and for the image I'm using `clip-path="url(#_clip)"`

```css
svg{width:90vh;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 208.23 200.22"><defs>
  
  <clipPath id="_clip">
       <path d="M70.28,189.78a149.9,149.9,0,0,1-13.79-8.33A122.87,122.87,0,0,0,70.28,189.78Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M126.47.05C95-.91,55.84,11.75,29.71,33.48l.45-.36c-39.1,52.11-2.4,128.95,37.57,155.47,12.55,6.94,25.83,11.17,38.86,11.57,51.64,1.57,100-27.44,101.58-79.08S178.11,1.62,126.47.05Z"/>
  </clipPath>
  
  </defs>
  <title>Asset 1</title>
  <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
       <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" height="240" width="250" clip-path="url(#_clip)"></image>
    </g> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `cls-1` *paths* to a `clipPath` definition (say with id `#clip_path`) and add an `image` element (a sample red image below) with style `url(#clip_path)` - see demo below:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 208.23 200.22"><defs>
  <style>
    .cls-1{fill:#eeeeef;}
    .cls-2{fill:url(#linear-gradient);}
    .cls-3{fill:url(#linear-gradient-2);}
    .cls-4{fill:url(#linear-gradient-3);}
    .mask {clip-path: url(#clip_path);}
  </style>
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" y1="108.72" x2="70.49" y2="108.72" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#9bdbf4"/>
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#29b2e7"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#8082be"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="-0.01" y1="189.83" x2="70.49" y2="189.83" xlink:href="#linear-gradient"/>
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-3" x1="-0.01" y1="112.73" x2="70.49" y2="112.73" xlink:href="#linear-gradient"/>
  <clipPath id="clip_path">
      <path class="cls-1" d="M126.47.05C95-.91,55.84,11.75,29.71,33.48l.45-.36c-39.1,52.11-2.4,128.95,37.57,155.47,12.55,6.94,25.83,11.17,38.86,11.57,51.64,1.57,100-27.44,101.58-79.08S178.11,1.62,126.47.05Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="M70.28,189.78a149.9,149.9,0,0,1-13.79-8.33A122.87,122.87,0,0,0,70.28,189.78Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="M28.17,35.61l-.44.38C11.43,50.4.59,68.36.59,88.53c0,33.76,24.51,71.09,55.91,92.92a149.9,149.9,0,0,0,13.79,8.33l.17.09C29.69,164.57-9.32,88.88,28.17,35.61Z"/>
  </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <title>Asset 1</title>
  <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
     <image class="mask" xlink:href="https://placehold.it/500/FF0000"></image>
     <path class="cls-2" d="M.59,88.53C.59,68.36,11.43,50.4,27.73,36-25.13,79.85,4.93,146.43,56.49,181.45,25.1,159.62.59,122.29.59,88.53Z"/><path class="cls-3" d="M70.49,189.89l0,0-.17-.09Z"/>
      <path class="cls-4" d="M28.17,35.61l-.44.38C11.43,50.4.59,68.36.59,88.53c0,33.76,24.51,71.09,55.91,92.92a149.9,149.9,0,0,0,13.79,8.33l.17.09C29.69,164.57-9.32,88.88,28.17,35.61Z"/>
  </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Managed to get this working, appreciate your assitance. My solution wasn't quite the same as this but it's useful to see multiple methods :)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find a solution for this by doing the following. The 2 answers do seem to also do the trick :)

```
<!-- SVG Shape saved as .svg in illustrator -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 208.23 200.22"><defs><style>.cls-1{}.cls-2{fill:url(#linear-gradient);}.cls-3{fill:url(#linear-gradient-2);}.cls-4{fill:url(#linear-gradient-3);}</style><linearGradient id="linear-gradient" y1="108.72" x2="70.49" y2="108.72" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/><stop offset="0" stop-color="#9bdbf4"/><stop offset="0" stop-color="#29b2e7"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#8082be"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="-0.01" y1="189.83" x2="70.49" y2="189.83" xlink:href="#linear-gradient"/><linearGradient id="linear-gradient-3" x1="-0.01" y1="112.73" x2="70.49" y2="112.73" xlink:href="#linear-gradient"/></defs><title>Asset 1</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><path class="cls-1" d="M70.28,189.78a149.9,149.9,0,0,1-13.79-8.33A122.87,122.87,0,0,0,70.28,189.78Z"/>

<!-- This is the path that the image should be contained withing. The "fill" is the id of the <defs> tag which defines what the image is -->
<path fill="url(#imgpattern)" class="cls-1" d="M126.47.05C95-.91,55.84,11.75,29.71,33.48l.45-.36c-39.1,52.11-2.4,128.95,37.57,155.47,12.55,6.94,25.83,11.17,38.86,11.57,51.64,1.57,100-27.44,101.58-79.08S178.11,1.62,126.47.05Z"/><path class="cls-2" d="M.59,88.53C.59,68.36,11.43,50.4,27.73,36-25.13,79.85,4.93,146.43,56.49,181.45,25.1,159.62.59,122.29.59,88.53Z"/><path class="cls-3" d="M70.49,189.89l0,0-.17-.09Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M28.17,35.61l-.44.38C11.43,50.4.59,68.36.59,88.53c0,33.76,24.51,71.09,55.91,92.92a149.9,149.9,0,0,0,13.79,8.33l.17.09C29.69,164.57-9.32,88.88,28.17,35.61Z"/><path class="cls-4" d="M28.17,35.61l-.44.38C11.43,50.4.59,68.36.59,88.53c0,33.76,24.51,71.09,55.91,92.92a149.9,149.9,0,0,0,13.79,8.33l.17.09C29.69,164.57-9.32,88.88,28.17,35.61Z"/></g></g>



<!-- This is what defines what the bg of SVG should be. Add your ACF code to xlink:href="" to echo the image. -->
<defs>
      <pattern id="imgpattern" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
        <image width="100%" height="100%"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"
               xlink:href="image1.jpg"/>
      </pattern>
  </defs>

</svg>
```